# Conditional summing T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, crystal-reports

This is a really simple question, I know it is. But can't for the life of me figure it out.

I have a few coloumns but the main ones are ReservationFee and Invoice ID.

Basically, there can be multiple "ReservationFees" in a single invoice. This value will be put on a crystal report, so I ideally need to sum up reservation fees for each invoice id.

**Example Data**

```
Invoice ID     Reservation Fee
1              200
1              300
2              100
3              350
3              100
```

**Expected Output**

```
Invoice ID     Reservation Fee
1              500
2              100
3              450
```

I have tried a few different sums and groupings but can't get it right, I'm blaming Monday morning!

Comment: Not duplicate, my answer was open to answers using crystal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to SUM in the server then:

```
SELECT [Invoice ID],
       SUM([Reservation Fee]) 
FROM Table 
GROUP BY [Invoice ID]
```

If you want to SUM in the Crystal then add a `command` or drag and drop your table

```
SELECT [Invoice ID], 
       [Reservation Fee]
FROM Table
```

Then right click in the `details section` and Select `Insert Group`.

Add the fields in the details section, Right Click on the `Reservation Fee` field and select insert running total.

In the window choose a name, select evaluate for each row and Reset on change of group the one you entered before.

Place the newly created field in the `Group Footer`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `GROUP BY` clause:

```
Select
    [Invoice ID],
    SUM([Reservation Fee]) [Reservation Fee]
From
    YourTable
GROUP BY [Invoice ID]
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with:

```
SELECT [Invoice Id], SUM([Reservation Fee]) AS [Reservation Fee]
FROM   dbo.YourTable
GROUP BY [Invoice Id]
```

Comment: Perhaps I was unclear in the question. This query along with the other answers gives me multiple lines for each InvoiceID, because of course there are multiple reservation fee's for each invoice.

Answer (score 0):

try this one.

```
declare @Invoice_table table 
(
Invoice_ID int ,     
Reservation_Fee money
)
insert into @Invoice_table values
(1              ,200),
(1              ,300),
(2              ,100),
(3              ,350),
(3              ,100)

SELECT SUM (Reservation_Fee) as Reservation_Fee, Invoice_ID from @Invoice_table group by Invoice_ID
```